# Converting datetime to different timezones with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, timezone

Im using the InstantAnswer source of the Bing API to retrieve flight status information in JSON format via **jQuery.getJSON**. This is an example of what im receiving:

```
if(typeof SearchCompleted == 'function') SearchCompleted({"SearchResponse":{"Version":"2.2","Query":{"SearchTerms":"LA1442"},"InstantAnswer":{
"Results":[{"ContentType":"FlightStatus","Title":"flight status for Lan Airlines 1442","ClickThroughUrl":"http:\/\/www.bing.com\/search?mkt=en-US&q=LA1442&form=SOAPGN","Url":"http:\/\/www.flightstats.com\/go\/FlightStatus\/flightStatusByFlight.do?id=239598315","InstantAnswerSpecificData":{"FlightStatus":{"AirlineCode":"LA","AirlineName":"Lan Airlines","FlightNumber":"1442","FlightName":"LA1442","FlightHistoryId":239598315,"StatusString":"Landed","StatusCode":76,"OnTimeString":"","ScheduledDeparture":"2011-09-22T17:25:00Z","UpdatedDeparture":"2011-09-22T17:15:00Z","ScheduledArrival":"2011-09-22T18:20:00Z","UpdatedArrival":"2011-09-22T18:17:00Z","OriginAirport":{"Code":"GYE","Name":"Guayaquil","TimeZoneOffset":-18000},"DestinationAirport":{"Code":"UIO","Name":"Quito","TimeZoneOffset":-18000},"DepartureGate":"","DepartureTerminal":"","ArrivalGate":"","ArrivalTerminal":"","PreviousSegment":{"FlightHistoryId":239598314,"OriginAirport":"EZE","DestinationAirport":"GYE"},"DataFreshness":1}}}]}}} /*
```

The information im having trouble with (timezone related) is this:

- Scheduled Departure: **2011-09-22T17:25:00Z**
- Scheduled Arrival: **2011-09-22T18:20:00Z**

Here is the problem: If the flight has already departed, i need to make a projection of which percentage of the flight path has been already travelled.

That would be easy to calculate IF both the Scheduled Departure and Scheduled Arrival fields would be in the **same** timezone as the computers current timezone (im using a clientside script only) -- but they are not. One of them is using the timezone in Ecuador (GMT -5) and the other is using the timezone in Chile (GMT -4).

My idea is:

1. convert both values to [unix timestamps](http://phpjs.org/functions/strtotime:554)
2. convert **both timestamps** to the **current computer's timezone**
3. calculate plane's travelled percentage with those 2 timestamps and [my computer's current timestamp](http://onlineaspect.com/examples/timezone/detect_timezone.js)

The step im having trouble is **No. 2** - Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the `Z` at the end of the string is for 'zulu time' http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/info/zulu.htm

Comment: yes, its zulu time structure (GMT) but using each city's timezone.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, but it's zulu time zulu time regardless of what timezone it's from?

Comment: no, zulu is just the GMT structure. Each timezone has a specific GMT value. For instance, Ecuador is GMT -5.

Comment: right, but zulu time is UTC meaning it has not timezone applied to it.  `NOAA satellites use Zulu Time or Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) as their time reference.`

Comment: you have a good point, then the question would be, how can i get the current UTC time in javascript to triangulate the flight travelled percentage with the other 2 values?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3710/discussion-between-andufo-and-iabstractdownvotefactory)