# Javascript multi date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I was looking for a similar issue here at Stackoverflow javascript multiple date display related, but couldn't find what I want.

Here this code: [demo javascript date](http://jsfiddle.net/fxdigi/AWDyM/)

I was trying to make the date based on different time zones for different cities. For example, I want to show the current date for New York in a div in this format:

```
Monday, January 30, 2012
```

..and another city like London in a different div in the same format:

```
Monday, January 30, 2012
```

If the day changes, then the date changes as well. Is there a way how to add GMT time to each city so that I can have as many cities as possible to display?

If there is a better way and a lot simpler using JQuery for example, it would be a lot better since it is easy to play around with that tool.

Comment: Java!=JavaScript  Please ***read*** the descriptions of tags you apply to a post!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520478/converting-datetime-to-different-timezones-with-javascript

Comment: hi Adrew. Sorry my mistake. next time I will be careful choosing the right tags. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use javascript as follow:

[Convert the local time to another time zone with this JavaScript](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/6016329)

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">

// function to calculate local time
// in a different city
// given the city's UTC offset
function calcTime(city, offset) {

    // create Date object for current location
    d = new Date();

    // convert to msec
    // add local time zone offset
    // get UTC time in msec
    utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

    // create new Date object for different city
    // using supplied offset
    nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));

    // return time as a string
    return "The local time in " + city + " is " + nd.toLocaleString();

}

// get Bombay time
alert(calcTime('Bombay', '+5.5'));

// get Singapore time
alert(calcTime('Singapore', '+8'));

// get London time
alert(calcTime('London', '+1'));

</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ Hemant. Thanks a lot mate. This code is good, but it gives java alert when loading the page. I wanted none alert, but a div to display each city date like for example: Friday, January 12 2012... I will try to find more resources. Thanks

Comment: @Fxdigi you can set the innerhtml of the div by calling this function as many times as you want

Comment: great job mate. Yes, that's excellent. now I can implement the reset of the goal. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
function AnotherCityDate(offset) {
    var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
    var dayNames=["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday",
    "Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]
    // create Date object for current location
    var d = new Date();
    // convert to msec
    // add local time zone offset 
    // get UTC time in msec
    utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    // create new Date object for different city
    // using supplied offset
    nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));
    // return time as a string
    return dayNames[nd.getDay()] + ', ' + monthNames[nd.getMonth()] + ' ' +
      nd.getDate() +  ', ' + nd.getFullYear();
}
```

Comment: Hi Cheery. Thanks mate for the script, but that doesn't seem to work. I test it on my server, but shows nothing. any idea why??!!

Comment: @Fxdigi        Sorry, there was a typo here `monthNames[ng.getMonth()]` should be `nd`, updated the code. It return the string, which you can insert by innerHTML wherever  you want.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I noticed that before, but even after the modification, nothing shows up on the server.

Comment: @Fxdigi  It is not suppose to do anything on the server - javascript runs in the user's browser. If you want do put the result of function into, let say, `<div id='out'></div>` you have to run the following js code (if you are using jQuery): `$('#out').html(AnotherCityDate(2));`, where 2 is GMT +2 offset for some city. If you are not using jQuery then it should be `document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = AnotherCityDate(2);`

Comment: Hi Cheery. Thanks a lot. it is ok, I got the idea. whether the code works or not, I believe you want me to duplicate the previous code, but with different naming for the variables so no conflict occurs if any function is called. Nice work. And thanks for the great tip.

Comment: hi mates. I just wanted to add something that you may get advantage of if you like to do so. This is a website has a very long code showing all time zone and dates for a lot of cities around the world. I hope you find it useful:[http://www.proglogic.com/code/javascript/time/worldclock.php]